# Can I use Nurbs curves as the bone display custom shape?

Tags: rigging, bones

I have a rigged mesh and am at the point where I'm trying to pretty it up.  I've created a few controller bones that I use to drive the IK.  I'd like to change their appearance by setting their Display/Custom Shape property.  Coming from Maya, I'm used to using NURBS shapes to make easy to identify shapes.  However, when I create a NURBS curve and use it as my bone's custom shape, nothing is displayed in the viewport.  I can set it to meshes or empties and they display fine - but not NURBS paths.

Is there a way I can use NURBS paths as my custom display shape?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply transform your curve into a mesh (alt C) and then use the mesh as custom shape. be prepared to adjust loc rot and scale of your mesh/curve (a problem also with simple meshes)